# Multiple Bootstrap Elements in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I'm trying to display stars based on an average rating (so if average rating is above 4, display 5 stars).

I have it working, but it seems like there should be a better way to do it instead of having to list out all the html elements.

```
<% if(ratingAverage > 4){ %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% } else if(ratingAverage > 3) {%>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% } %>
```

Is there a way to assign the span to a variable and then just multiply it by the amount of times it is needed. So like var glyph * 3 and it will list it 3 times.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't look like a nodejs issue, but rather an ejs templating issue. Are you using the ejs template engine?

Comment: I am using the EJS template engine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop..

```
<% for(var i=0; i<ratingAverage; i++) { %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% } %>
```